# How to post raw data using JAX-RS 2.0 client API

Tags: jax-rs, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I have a raw `inputStream` and a `HttpServletRequest` i need to send the whole inputStream recieved as well as the headers to another servlet(as it is) using JAX-RS client.

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

WebTarget reTarget = client.target("http://localhost:8100/Server");
Invocation retargetInvocation = reTarget.request().??
Response.Response response = retargetInvocation.invoke();
```

How should my invocation be made for the post Request `Invocation retargetInvocation = reTarget.request().post(Entity<T>)`.The inputStream may contain any Raw data

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`Entity.entity(inputStream, MediaType.YOUR_MEDIA_TYPE_TYPE)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Entity.html#entity%28T,%20javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType%29)

For the `MediaType` (and headers), I would inject `@Context HttpHeaders` into your resource class. It makes it easier to lookup specific headers. You could do

```
Entity.entity(inputStream, httpHeaders.getMediaType());
```

You could also iterate through the headers, in building the request

```
Invocation.Builder builder = client.target(url).request();
for (String header: headers.getRequestHeaders().keySet()) {
    builder.header(header, headers.getHeaderString(header));
}
Response response = builder.post(Entity.entity(is, headers.getMediaType()));
```

So altogether, it might look something like

```
@Context HttpHeaders headers;

@POST
public Response doForward(InputStream is) {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/...";
    Invocation.Builder builder = client.target(url).request();
    for (String header: headers.getRequestHeaders().keySet()) {
        builder.header(header, headers.getHeaderString(header));
    }
    Response response = builder.post(Entity.entity(is, headers.getMediaType()));
    return Response.ok(response.getEntity()).build();
}
```

Do keep in mind though that the `Client` is an expensive object to create. You could reuse the same `Client` for different requests, as long as you don't mess with it's configurations after it is created.

If you iterate through all the headers like I did above, you will get a warning in the log about allowing restricted headers. You can disable the warning with  a System property

```
System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true");
```

But honestly I am not sure about what the warning is for, and any security implications, so you may to look into that.

Comment: as i m using Grizzly framework i was not able to get the `@Context HttpHeaders` therefore i injected `Provider<Request> grizzlyRequestProvider` to get the required headers.Thanks for the help